# Implement Wikitude in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, typescript, wikitude

I'm trying to implement Wikitude Architect View in Angular 2 using this reference 
https://github.com/jinhong-/nativescript-wikitudearchitectview/blob/master/demo/app/main-page.ts
I'm trying to implement this piece of code in an Angular 2 way

```js
import * as app from 'application';
import * as platform from 'platform';
import { Demo } from "./main-view-model";
import { View } from "ui/core/view";
import * as frameModule from 'ui/frame'

function pageLoaded(args) {
  var page = <View>args.object;
  page.bindingContext = new Demo();
  var architectView = page.getViewById<any>("architectView");
  console.log('pageLoaded');
}
```

```html
<page xmlns="http://schemas.nativescript.org/tns.xsd" 
      xmlns:ar="nativescript-wikitudearchitectview" 
      loaded="pageLoaded">
      <GridLayout rows="*, auto">
        <ar:ArchitectView id="architectView" urlString="http://10.20.30.79:8888" urlLoaded='urlLoaded' urlLoadError='urlLoadError' urlInvoked='urlInvoked'/>
      </GridLayout>
</page>
```

so far I have :

```js
@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "app.xml"
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
  
  ngOnInit() {
    var page = <View>args.object;
    page.bindingContext = new Demo();
    var architectView = page.getViewById<any>("architectView");
    console.log('pageLoaded');
  }
```

```html
      <GridLayout rows="*, auto">
        <ar:ArchitectView id="architectView" urlString="http://10.20.30.79:8888" urlLoaded='urlLoaded' urlLoadError='urlLoadError' urlInvoked='urlInvoked'>
        </ar:ArchitectView>
        <Button row="1" text="hello"></Button>
      </GridLayout>
```

The main part is converting these 3 lines into Angular 2 format

```
var page = <View>args.object;
page.bindingContext = new Demo();
var architectView = page.getViewById<any>("architectView");
```

But I don't know how can I do that.

Answer (score 1):

First, in your `html` file you'll need to change `<ar:ArchitectView` to `<ArchitectView`, and to support that you can add this to `main.ts`:

```
var architectView = require("nativescript-wikitudearchitectview");
registerElement("ArchitectView", () => architectView.ArchitectView);
```

Second, take a look at this page: http://docs.nativescript.org/angular/tutorial/ng-chapter-6 and search for '#email'. So in your view add:

```
<ArchitectView #architectView
```

And in the component:

```
@ViewChild("architectView") architectView: ElementRef;
```

Comment: After add this code the error i am getting is : this method only has to be called right after the object has been constructed.     so the <ArchitectView> can only be called once the page has been loaded how can i do that?

Comment: I would also like to know how to include a wikitude view inside an Angular2 component, because i am using Ionic2. 
I tried to follow this example, but the build threw an error that cannot find the module `nativescript-wikitudearchitectview`, even if i had installed it previously.
Furthermore, after placing the view inside the component, how can I insert a wikitude world inside it?